# How to create a web page, with a fixed background image, with the top div scroling, but to smoothly scroll the bottom fixed bg image as well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page like this;

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="top">q</div>
  <div class="top">w</div>
  <div class="top">e</div>
  <div class="top">r</div>
  <div class="top">t</div>
  <div class="top">y</div>
</div>
```

div `bg` is having a fixed background, so that it will stay as such. `top`s are having no bg images, but some has solid bg colors. They have fixed width of 100% and heights of 400px. Since some of them have no bd color, the bottom `bg`'s image is visible. but i want the `bg` image to scroll, slower than the speed of `top`s.

Here is a page, to let u know, what i am trying to accomplish. **[JPL Home](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/)**. In this page, you can see that the bottom image scrolls, while we scroll down, with the top layer `div`s, but slower compared to them. How can I do this? is this HTML + CSS alone, or with the help of any JS library?

Comment: Google for CSS parallax effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is some good jquery plugins for u, like this:
http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/